# Targeting framework v4.0 application to v3.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, vb.net-2010

I want to compile vb.net application with TargetFrameworkVersion v4.0, and supportedRuntime v2.0 in app.conig. Then I would like to use System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion() to check the running framework version and exclude the block of code specific to / supported by v4.0 only.  Is it possible?

The purpose is that I want to run the basic code supported by both v2.0 and v4.0, and also  run the advanced code supported by v4.0 only in case v4.0 is installed in the client system.

Comment: It is very difficult to get right, the assembly format has changed in .NET 4 so CLR v2 won't be able to load it.  You have to isolate all the .NET 4 specific code in a separate assembly and load it yourself.  Reflection code required.  It just doesn't make sense to do this, getting .NET 4.0 installed is too trivial.